# django model referencing object from other class

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

Hi there pretty new to django but considering the below models, with their relationships, how do I create a read only field for the object that is a reference to a field in another class? I've looked for a while on stackoverflow, but not sure what kind of model reference that would be.

The basic logic for this being: 
I have this server rack that sites on a floor in a server room, and I'm associating it to a rack position, and row to manage power consumption and other goodies. Just for my end-user's reference I want a read only field to show them what row this rack lives in, and its derived from the rack position. I'd been fiddling around with creating a method to look it up, but can't seem to figure out the syntax or find something related on the django admin pages.

Any ideas would be super appreciated, I really could use the help as I've been staring through docs forever, and can't seem to find a relevant model reference for this.

```
class rack(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Rack"
        verbose_name_plural = "Racks"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.position)

    def row(self, obj):
        return self.position.row

    position = models.OneToOneField("rackposition")
    row = row(position.row.row)
    asstag = models.CharField("Asset Tag", max_length=200, unique=True)
    rackunits = models.IntegerField("Rack Units")

class rackposition(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Rack Position"
        verbose_name_plural = "Rack Positions"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.position)

    position = models.CharField("Position", max_length=35, primary_key=True)
    row = models.ForeignKey("row")

class row(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Row"
        verbose_name_plural = "Rows"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.row) + "." + str(self.suite)

    row = models.CharField("Row ID", max_length=200, unique=True)
    suite = models.ForeignKey(suite, blank=False)
    power_budget = models.IntegerField("Power Budget")
    power_volt = models.IntegerField("Power Voltage")
    dual_bus = models.BooleanField("Dual Bus", default=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a method. Assuming you have a rack instance called `my_rack`, you can get its row with `my_rack.position.row`.

Note, you should really follow PEP8 and use CamelCase for your class names.

If you want to see it as a readonly field in the admin, you will need to define a method either on the model or on the ModelAdmin class. For example:

```
class RackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Rack
    readonly_fields = ('row',)

    def row(self, obj):
        return obj.position.row
```

Comment: would this be a read only field such as this?
row = my_rack.position.row

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry Daniel let me clarify. If I want this to be on the Admin object field, when you click on an object, what model reference would that be? It's not really a field in the db, so is there a reference I would use for generic read only fields in the form? Or do i have to create my own?

Comment: Ah I didn't realise you wanted it as a readonly field. See my update.

Comment: Same logic on models.py for the object field? I got it in the admin for using in a list, but if the enduser clicks on the object that info is not going to be present.

Comment: And I'm assuming that this can't be a filterable field right since it isn't an object in the db just a view?