# Object reference to django model - missing "object"

Tags: python, django

I have data that looks like:
`Store    Count_Customers    Count_Purchases 
BestBuy    2                  2 
Target     1                  1 
Target     4                  3 
Walmart    5                  1 
Target     9                  1`

I want to use a django model to produce a list of stores, and summaries by stores.

So I have models.py as:

```
class UniqueStore(models.Model):
    store = models.CharField(db_column='store', max_length=100, unique=True)


class Summarize(object):
    store = models.ForeignKey(UniqueStore,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True) 
    sum_customers = models.IntegerField(u"count_customers") 
    sum_purchases = models.IntegerField(u"count_purchases")
```

and my_summary.py as a management command as

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Summary by store"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print("Stores: {}".format(UniqueStore.objects.all().count()))
        print("Facts: {}".format(Summarize.objects.all().sum()))
```

but even before I run python manage.py my_summary, I get the error `unresolved attribute reference: object`

Could help me understand how to fix this error?

I dont see this resolved in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/

If it has to do with metaclass ([django model referencing object from other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649977/django-model-referencing-object-from-other-class)), could someone provide additional resources/explanation?

Comment: What do you mean "but even before I run `python manage.py my_summary`"?  What are you executing that results in the error message?

Comment: IDE Pycharm highlights the error, and then yes when I try to run that command I get `AttributeError: type object 'Summarize' has no attribute 'objects'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize is type object but it needs to be type Model instead.